# How to detect a collision between selected object and other objects in the list?

Tags: python, list, pygame

How can I detect if there is a collision between car and other elements in traffic (`traffico`)?

- `Car.posAtt` is actual position of car in the map.
- `Car.visione` is a `Rect` in front of the car to create distance between each other.
- `Car.ingombro` is a `Rect` of the image.

Obviously when `car.visione` detects a collision with one of the other `car.ingombro`s it is going to stop.

```
for car in traffico:
    if countTrafficLight == 1:
        if car.quadPart == 2:
            if car.posAtt[1] < 430 or car.posAtt[1] > 435:                   
                car.Move()
                pygame.draw.rect(schermoGioco, BLUE, car.visione)
                if car.posAtt == CoordToTurn(car.quadPart, car.quadArr):
                    car.Turn()
        elif car.quadPart == 3:
            if car.posAtt[0] > 570 or car.posAtt[0] < 565:
                car.Move()
                pygame.draw.rect(schermoGioco, BLUE, car.visione)
                if car.posAtt == CoordToTurn(car.quadPart, car.quadArr):
                    car.Turn()
        elif car.quadPart == 4:
            if car.posAtt[1] < 210 or car.posAtt[1] > 220:

                car.Move()
                pygame.draw.rect(schermoGioco, BLUE, car.visione)
                if car.posAtt == CoordToTurn(car.quadPart, car.quadArr):
                    car.Turn()
        elif car.quadPart == 1:
            car.Move()
            pygame.draw.rect(schermoGioco, BLUE, car.visione)
            if car.posAtt == CoordToTurn(car.quadPart, car.quadArr):
                    car.Turn()
```

Comment: This is far too broad/vague, can you be more specific about what you've tried, what the issue is, etc.? Also, variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to implement this is to convert your `car` into a PyGame Sprite object.  This would allow the code to use a `SpriteGroup` and the powerful `groupcollide` functions.

In lieu of this, it should be possible to simply loop through N x N times, checking each car against the others.  I'm not sure from your question exactly what the `ingombro` rectangle represents, but below the code assumes it's the boundary-rectangle around the car itself.

```
def carCollidesWith( test_car, traffic ):
    """Returns the car-in-traffic that test_car collies with, or None"""
    result = None   
    for car in traffic:
        if ( car is not test_car ):  # don't collide with yourself
            if ( test_car.ingombro.colliderect( car.ingombro ) ):
                result = car
                break

    return result
```

However there's many other ways to do this more efficiently.  Have a look at the pygame `Rect` library [documentation](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.colliderect).

Comment: hi, can i write you privately beacause i need a lot of help? and where?

Comment: @AMBROSIO: In my opinion it's not appropriate for you to ask someone who answered your question for help outside stackoverflow because the whole point of the website is to help others with similar problems — plus it's somewhat awkward if they want to say "No".